# How to preserve comments in Eclipse JDT

Tags: java, parsing, comments, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I'm using Eclipse JDT to modify java source code. This happens in three steps:

- At first I create an instance of org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit and call it's *accept()* method with an ASTVisitor
- Then I manipulate the CompilationUnit. I remove and add ASTNodes to the tree (this is not shown here)
- Then I write *compilationUnit.toString()* back to a file.

Creation of the compilation unit:

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS11);
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
parser.setSource(readSourceCode("FooBar.java"));
parser.setStatementsRecovery(false);
Hashtable<String, String> options = JavaCore.getDefaultOptions();
options.put("org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.doc.comment.support", "enabled");
parser.setCompilerOptions(options);
CompilationUnit compUnit = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
compUnit.accept(new FooBarVisitor());
```

Write changed compUnit to a file:

```
writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFilePath));
Map options = DefaultCodeFormatterConstants.getEclipseDefaultSettings();
CodeFormatter formatter = ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter(options);
String sourceCode = result.getCompilationUnit().toString();
int formatType = CodeFormatter.K_COMPILATION_UNIT | CodeFormatter.F_INCLUDE_COMMENTS | CodeFormatter.K_UNKNOWN;
TextEdit edit = formatter.format(formatType, sourceCode, 0, sourceCode.length(), 0, System.getProperty("line.separator"));
Document document = new Document(sourceCode);
edit.apply(document);
writer.write(document.get());
writer.close();
```

Example file which contains multiple comments:

```
package foo.bar;
/**
 * Multiline
 * Javadoc
 */
public class FooBar {
    // inline comment
    private String foo = "bar";
    public String getFoo() {
        /*
         * Multiline
         * comment
         */
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Corresponding output:

```
package foo.bar;
/**
 * Multiline Javadoc
 */
public class FooBar {
    private String foo = "bar";
    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

There are two problems: Firstly the multiline javadoc is compressed to only one line. Secondly, the other two comments are removed completely.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you start losing information when you do `compilationUnit.toString()`. Later when you format the text, you finally lose any existing formatting.

Instead, I recommend to learn how to use `ASTRewrite`, which allows you to incrementally apply your changes into the existing AST. The goal is to let the rewrite generate the minimal `TextEdit`s that can be `applied` to the (original!) document.

If using `ASTRewrite` inside your visitor is not an option, you could even try using `ASTRewrite` in "recording" mode, see `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit.recordModifications()`.